# filtering datagridview data using "NOT LIKE" condition is unsuccessful.how to modify the code?

Tags: vb.net

I am developing a simple library management system. i try to filter data with "NOT LIKE" condition. the following code which i use is working, no errors.But gives mixed results.when i filter only "Gunasena" in publisher data rows with Added_Date.but this gives Gnasena+godage datas.Added_Date filter is totally correct.Help me to solve this problem,Thanks. this code works 100% correct in "LIKE" condition.

```
Private Sub combobox4_TextChange(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles combobox4.TextChange
    Dim filters As New List(Of String)

    If combobox1.Text = "Added Date" And withoutButton.Checked Then
        filters.Add("[Added_Date] LIKE '" & combobox2.Text & "%' And [Author] NOT LIKE '" & 
            combobox4.Text & "%'")
    End If

    If combobox1.Text = "Added Date" And withoutButton.Checked Then
        filters.Add("[Added_Date] LIKE '" &
            combobox2.Text & "%' And [Publisher] not LIKE '" & combobox4.Text & "%'")
    End If
    BooksBindingSource.Filter = String.Join(" Or ", filters)
End Sub
```

Comment: is added_date a string, or a datetime data type?...if its a date (which it should be), better off using a between instead of a LIKE...between Jan 01 1999 and Dec 31 1999 for example

Comment: Ctznkane525, added_date is a string not datetime data type.

Comment: i guess first part of every filter works but second part has a problem

Comment: Your if blocks are the same.  Added_Date should be a date, not a string.

Comment: If would be helpful to know how your date string look exactly. If they are formatted like `"2010/07/17"` (i.e. yyyy/MM/dd) then you can still use BETWEEN.

Comment: Added_Date is a string. filtering it fine. no any errors. But Author/Publisher filtering is wrong. how to modify the code?

Comment: Any help please!